# Prove that $3\log n$ is $O(\exp(0.001n))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, asymptotics

First time posting here. Hi math stack-exchange community!

I have a bonus question on my assignment and I am having trouble proving it. The main reason is that I am only limited to using the rules they provided me. Can anyone help me with this? I've been stuck at it for hours.

Here is where I got to: 
$$3log(n) = O(3n) \space -by \space Rule 7$$
$$O(3n) = O(e^{bn})\space -by \space Rule 5 \space and \space 6$$

---

**Below is the actual question. Prove that:**

[image]

Here are the rules that I am allowed to use and also an example of how it should be formatted.

[image: Here are the rules]

Comment: You've almost got it.  You just need to use Rule 4 (transitivity) to connect the two statements.

Comment: @DanBrumleve can you show me specifically how?

Answer (score 0):

$$
3log(n)=O(3n) − 7
$$

$$
O(3n)=O(e^{bn}) − 5, 6
$$

$b$, here, can be any positive number. Without loss of generality, choose $b = 0.001$

Now, by virtue of property 4,

$$
3log(n)=O(3n)
$$
and,
$$
O(3n)=O(e^{0.0001n})
$$
implies that,
$$3log(n) = O(e^{0.0001n}) $$